# How to deploy Node.js / Express app with typescript on heroku?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku, deployment

I want to deploy node.js / express server app on heroku.
I tried with this [blog](https://medium.com/@grantspilsbury/build-and-deploy-a-node-express-server-to-heroku-in-10-steps-70c936ab15dc).

But it didn't work. The parts of my code are below.

server.ts

[image: server.ts]

[image: server.ts]

package.json

[image: package.json]

Comment: Please describe the problem. "Didn't work" is useless, diagnostically. If it worked, you wouldn't be here. It's like going to a doctor and when they ask "What seems to be the nature of your medical emergency", answering that "something is wrong". What did you try? What happened then? What did you expect instead? Also, please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1):

Ahh. You have messed up in the `package.json` file. What you have done is you have included the `dependencies` in the `devDependencies`.
Remember one thing always, when you are going to push an app to Heroku it prunes the `devDependencies`.

Actually, this is the main cause your server is not starting up because there are not required modules.

**Run this command to move your `devDependencies` to `dependencies`**:

```sh
npm install <module-name> --save-dev
```

This thing will solve your problem. If you face any other problem related to the configuration then follow this article - https://dev.to/hte305/simple-deploy-typescript-application-to-heroku-5b6g